Parametrized bounds in the generation of Random Numbers in Haskell
I'm quite new in Haskell and I'm trying to create a function that generates an array of finite Numbers taking into account some starting and ending bound . If I use the following function ...
 finiteRandoms :: (Eq n, Num n, RandomGen g, Random a, Num a) => n -> g -> ([a], g)
 finiteRandoms 0 g = ([], g)
 finiteRandoms n g =
     let (value, newGen) = randomR (20,100) g
         (restOfList, finalGen) = finiteRandoms (n-1) newGen
     in  (value:restOfList, finalGen)

and I run the following command ...
finiteRandoms 3 (mkStdGen 3)

I obtain an array of Int with the new generator
([61,33,82],StdGen {unStdGen = SMGen 9186733390819170434 2092789425003139053})

What I'm trying to do is to add two new parameters to the function that marks the starting and ending point . In the function I have shared, it represents the numbers 20 and 100 . Something like this
finiteRandoms :: (Eq n, Num n, RandomGen g, Random a, Num a) => n -> n -> n-> g -> ([a], g)
   finiteRandoms 0 start end g = ([], g)
   finiteRandoms n start end g =
         let (value, newGen) = randomR (start,end) g
             (restOfList, finalGen) = finiteRandoms (n-1) newGen
         in  (value:restOfList, finalGen)

But when I load it through ghci I get the following error
randomSample.hs:19:10: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Couldn't match expected type: n -> g0 -> ([a0], g0)
                  with actual type: (a1, b)
    • In the pattern: (restOfList, finalGen)
      In a pattern binding:
        (restOfList, finalGen) = finiteRandoms (n - 1) newGen
      In the expression:
        let
          (value, newGen) = randomR (start, end) g
          (restOfList, finalGen) = finiteRandoms (n - 1) newGen
        in (value : restOfList, finalGen)
    • Relevant bindings include
        value :: n (bound at randomSample.hs:18:11)
        end :: n (bound at randomSample.hs:17:24)
        start :: n (bound at randomSample.hs:17:18)
        n :: n (bound at randomSample.hs:17:16)
        finiteRandoms :: n -> n -> n -> g -> ([a], g)
          (bound at randomSample.hs:16:2)
   |
19 |          (restOfList, finalGen) = finiteRandoms (n-1) newGen
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

randomSample.hs:20:11: error: [GHC-25897]
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘n’
      ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          finiteRandoms :: forall n g a.
                           (Eq n, Num n, RandomGen g, Random a, Num a) =>
                           n -> n -> n -> g -> ([a], g)
        at randomSample.hs:15:2-92
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          finiteRandoms :: forall n g a.
                           (Eq n, Num n, RandomGen g, Random a, Num a) =>
                           n -> n -> n -> g -> ([a], g)
        at randomSample.hs:15:2-92
    • In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘value’
      In the expression: value : restOfList
      In the expression: (value : restOfList, finalGen)
    • Relevant bindings include
        value :: n (bound at randomSample.hs:18:11)
        end :: n (bound at randomSample.hs:17:24)
        start :: n (bound at randomSample.hs:17:18)
        n :: n (bound at randomSample.hs:17:16)
        finiteRandoms :: n -> n -> n -> g -> ([a], g)
          (bound at randomSample.hs:16:2)
   |
20 |      in  (value:restOfList, finalGen)
   |           ^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.

How can I parametrized this two bounds (start/end) ? Thanks.

You forgot to add the start and end in the recursive call, start and end also need to be of type g
finiteRandoms :: (Eq n, Num n, RandomGen g, Random a, Num a) => n -> a -> a -> g -> ([a], g)
finiteRandoms 0 start end g = ([], g)
finiteRandoms n start end g =
     let (value, newGen) = randomR (start,end) g
         (restOfList, finalGen) = finiteRandoms (n-1) start end newGen
     in  (value:restOfList, finalGen)
But likely, it is better to work with a helper function here:
finiteRandoms :: (Eq n, Num n, RandomGen g, Random a, Num a) => a -> a -> n -> g -> ([a], g)
finiteRandoms start end = go
   where go 0 g = ([], g)
         go n g =
             let (value, newGen) = randomR (start,end) g
                 (restOfList, finalGen) = go (n-1) newGen
             in  (value:restOfList, finalGen)
We then for example generate five numbers between twenty and hundred with:
ghci> finiteRandoms 20 100 5 (mkStdGen 3)
([70,50,99,83,50],781515869 652912057)


Nice . Thanks a lot . Far away from the refactoring and that is clearer your way, Is there any other reason ?

@Yago: well it makes the helper function cleaner, but often the order of parameters is also useful: the most changing one is often last, since we can do f = finiteRandom 20 100 to then use it as f 5 someRandom, f 10 someOtherRandom, for example to first generate 5 items, and then 10 with the same range.
